# PhpStorm: change the style of a parameter hint

Tags: phpstorm

Since I updated my PhpStorm, whenever I type a method, it mentions me the parameter hint.

Like so:

[image]

I wanted to know if there's a way to change its style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why I couldn't find an option to change the style of the parameter hint, was because I was looking on a PHP code style instead of a general font style.

Going to `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General` and then choosing the "Parameter Hint" and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

This is now found in `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Language Defaults`

Then choose "Inline parameter hint"

Version: 2017.1